# How do i import asset file from github to unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

https://youtu.be/Sqb-Ue7wpsI
This is the tutorial link. In this tutorial discription there is asset link. i download this and extract this file. but now, how do i import this assets in the unity?

Comment: You take them all and drag them into your Assets folder (except the Readme and DS_Store file ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are two ways to do this.

1. Open the folder (which the assets are in) in the file manager. Then drag the assets into the unity project.
2. You can also do it directly in unity. You can go in the top bar and do
   asset-> import new asset . From there, you navigate to the folder that the assets are in and import them all.